# Reinclusion to Wayback Machine?

Tags: archive.org

Due to unwanted personal information from long ago I requested a site to be removed from the Wayback Machine internet archive. When you check for it on web.archive.org it shows:

```
"This URL has been excluded from the Wayback Machine."
```

Now I want it to be reincluded with the current (and future) content on the site. When I initially requested removal I received an email from archive.org with details and they finished with, " If you have any other questions or concerns, please let us know." I have replied numerous times about reinclusion for the current site and haven't received a reply.

What can I do to have the site reincluded in the Wayback Machine for current and future content? I have already changed robots.txt to allow access.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a better question for [webmasters.se].

Comment: Is there a way for me to transfer this question there automatically?

Comment: I've voted to migrate. If four other people agree (or one Community Moderator), it'll be migrated. I don't know how long that will take. You may be better off deleting this and re-posting there.

Comment: Well, fyi I posted there (Webmasters) and it has been put on hold because "Questions here are required to about a website under your control. You'll need to contact them or ask in their forum."

Comment: It's your site, isn't it?

Comment: I guess I see their point: You're asking about archive.org, but that's obviously not your site. I would have thought this would have been akin to questions about search engine results, and I know they have questions about them.

Comment: Exactly. There are plenty of questions that relate to Google etc. Inconsistent moderation is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

What you want -- "only show content collected after this date", is not supported by the Internet Archive's software.

Comment: Since I asked that the personal information be removed, that data should not exist in the Internet Archive, correct? If so, then I just want the site to be re-included. Since the old data doesn't exist, there should be no problem. Are you implying that the Internet Archive doesn't actually delete the data and instead "hides" the data, but you actually still have this data?