# Can an excluded URL from Wayback Machine be included again in future by Internet Archive?

Tags: archive.org

I have claimed a copyright on my website content and it has been removed from the wayback machine. Now it says "this url has been excluded from wayback machine". My question is can it be included again in future if I post new website content on this domain or sell it?
If yes, will it also include the previous content which I requested to remove?

Answer (score 2):

In a similar situation, I simply sent an email to info@archive.org requesting that my website be reincluded in the Wayback Machine. The following day they informed me that they had enabled archives for my website from the day of my request onward. In my request, I had actually said that reinclusion of past captures would be fine with me, but, as indicated by their reply, no past captures were reincluded.

Comment: An older similar question: [Reinclusion to Wayback Machine?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88766/reinclusion-to-wayback-machine) (I'm adding this comment so that the two questions become linked.)